# Saving of Draft is failing

Tags: customization, autosave

When using the classic editor, I am able to save drafts just fine.

When using the normal editor, everything works except that I can't save drafts. I can publish just fine. But it otherwise gives me "Updating failed".

How do I fix the hanging saving issue?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't have anything to do with the plugins error?

Comment: @Castiblanco Yes - I've fixed that.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it really seems like another plugin problem, what happens if you switch your theme to twentyfifteen or another default WordPress theme?

Comment: Open up your browser's dev tools and see if there's any output in the console. E.g. Chrome right click + inspect. Then try going to the classic editor, make a few changes to update the draft, and see if any errors show up. This could point you to the offending plugin or theme. Odds are what Castiblanco is saying.. Start w/ a stock WP w/ no plugins + theme and if that doesn't work, then that's noteworthy, otherwise its most likely a plugin/theme issue.